# Where are the Ubuntu Snappy Personal builds available for testing?

Tags: snap

In January 2016, builds were suspended, but were suggested to come back during the 16.10 development cycle. I can't find anything, even though 16.10 has been released.

Is there a private repository to test?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, Ubuntu Core only uses snaps. You can get Ubuntu Core images [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/).